# Is it possiblet to use androids localized german folder (drawable-de) for Austria?

Tags: android, image, localization

I've got german images in my android app. These images are inside the drawable-de folder. Works nice. But when I changed my devices language in Germen (Austria) the app uses the default (english) images.
Is it possible to use the german images for other german speeking countries, without duplicate them?

Thank you for your help

Comment: It works fine for string values. And I would assuming that Android is intelligent enough to check `-de-rAT` -> '-de' -> default for all resource types. U sure you don't have a different problem appearing as if wrong drawables are used?

Comment: Thx for the quick answer. My string.xml file works fine. But android takes the "wrong"/default images instead of the German once. I don't want to make a programmatically solution :-(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create alias resources for that situation:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/providing-resources.html#AliasResources

Answer (score 1):

What Android version do you use? I just tested an application that had neutral images on res/drawable and German images in res/drawable-de. In addition the application has neutral strings in values, German strings in values-de, and Austrian German strings in values-de-rAT.

So there is an Austrian specific strings but no Austrian specific flag image. This is why I expected Android to use German flag image. It did that corrently. I was using Android 4.1 (API 16).

Then I downgraded the application using Android 2.3 (API 10) and it worked again. This means image cascading works just like it should at least starting from Android 2.3. I do not have any order SDK instaled so I could not test them.

Here is a screenshot about by project.

[image: Android project]

Answer (score 0):

Use `getResources().getConfiguration().locale.getCountry();` or `getLanguage()` which returns the country/language in use. Then, in your code, load a different image.